# Export User details in Office 365 tenant as csv file by connecting with powershell in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, export-to-csv

The need to export the user details as a csv file which is stored in PSObject. Exporting as csv file is need to be done with C#. Need help ?

// code

```
        String UserName = "username";
        String Password = "password";
        SecureString securepassword = new SecureString();                    
        foreach (char c in Password)
            securepassword.AppendChar(c);
        PSCredential Credential = new PSCredential(UserName, securepassword);

        InitialSessionState initialstate = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initialstate.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"MSOnline" });                   

        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialstate);          
        runSpace.Open();

        PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Connect-MsolService").AddParameter("Credential", Credential);
        PS.Invoke();

        PowerShell PS1 = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-msoluser");
         
        Collection<PSObject> userdetails = PS1.Invoke();
       
        runSpace.Close();
```

Comment: Get-msoluser | Export-Csv  -Path "C:/example/data.csv"

Comment: This need to be done using C# without using the direct PowerShell command